# Symfony2 route that enforces HTTPS without redirection

Tags: symfony

How can I define a route in Symfony2 that requires HTTPS but does not automatically redirect from HTTP?

For example, I already know that I can set the "scheme", such as:

```
 demo:
     resource: "@DemoBundle/Controller/DemoController.php"
     type:     annotation
     prefix:   /api/demo
     schemes:  [https]
```

This will redirect the user from "http://www.example.com/api/demo/{route}" to "https://www.example.com/api/demo/{route}". However, I want the attempt to use "http" to fail with a 404 or 500 error, while a direct attempt to use "https" is routed successfully.

**UPDATE:**

I kept the "schemes" parameter in the routing file and added the following to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} api
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}/ssl-only.php [R,L]
```

Comment: You should not send a 404 or 500 error. 404 is for a missing resource and 500 for server errors. The correct codes are 302 and 301 (temporary or permanent redirection), what Symfony2 does. But if you really want it, you should add a rule in your .htaccess and throw a 404 error on all http requests

Comment: I'm not married to the idea of throwing a 404 or 500 error, in particular, but I do want to throw a hard error, and not redirect the user, be temporary or permanent. If I allowed a redirection to the HTTPS version of the resource, then the consumer of my api could define his endpoint with HTTP only and develop an otherwise usable api client that permanently sends insecure data, which I want to explicitly prevent. If possible, I would like to accomplish this inside Symfony and not with HTACCESS.

Comment: OK so throw the code 400 (bad request) with a rule in your .htaccess. Symfony can throw it, but it will be faster if your server does

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to remove `schemes: [https]` from the routing, and instead check the scheme in Controller if it was not HTTPS redirect it the specific error page you want:

```
public function yourRoutingAction()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->getScheme() == 'http') {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('specific_route', 301));
    }
    //Otherwise continue your process
    //You can change the Status code to whatever you want instead of 301
}
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Despite initially saying I didn't want to update my .htaccess file, that seems to be the best option.